# View controller dealloced by __delayedPerformDealloc

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have an interesting problem that has me stumped.  I have a view that is displayed on top of another view (using addView).  The second view does not fill the entire screen on the iPhone.  Both views are managed by view controllers.  The second view controller then presents a modal view controller that fills the screen (specifically MFMessageComposeViewController).

All of this works great the first time.  However, when I dismiss the modal view controller the second time, the dealloc method on the presenting view controller (the one that presents the modal) gets called by __delayedPerformDealloc.

The containing view controller has retained the inner view controller, so I can't figure out what list the inner view controller got on that caused it to be dealloc'd.

Has anyone else seen this?

Tools: Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 6, iPhone 5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a bonehead move by me.  The controller in question was being passed as a delegate and was assigned to a member variable in the init method but was released in the dealloc method.  D'oh!